# How to secure Django Rest API

Tags: django, api, rest

I created custom survey with React and I want to send data once survey is complete to Drip (user managing platform) https://developer.drip.com/

I can't connect website with Drip API directly - it'll expose API Key. I decided to use Python Django with REST as proxy.
My question - what's possible threats and how can I secure my Backend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per drip documentation - you could use:

> OAuth 2 authentication (for public integrations)

this won't expose your API Key

There are a lot of materials on Google, how to do OAuth2 with React.

If you prefer to go with the proxy through Django with REST - then [here you can find some informations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)